# Does exist any way to force child class to have at least one field with a specified attribute?

Tags: c#, oop

Suppose we have created an attribute named [Mandatory]. Those exist any way to force a child class to have at least on field with this attribute while the parent class does not have any field??
For example suppose this:

```
class parent{
    public abstract void doSomething(){};
}
```

What should I add to the parent class so child class had to be something like this:

```
class parent{
    [Mandatory] public field1;
    public override void doSomething(){ // do something ...};
}
```

And if it did not contain `field1` it could not be compiled. Does exist something like this in c#?

### Update

The parent class is only to apply a rule that Already staff respect but I wanted to guarantee that everybody have to declare at least on field. I think this is not a case of object oriented application. But I'm trying to force them obey this convention using oop! If it is not the correct way please inform me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the purpose of the field?  Could you not use an interface with a _property_ instead?

Comment: Why don't you define an abstract field/property/method in your base class? That forces derived classes to override it.

Comment: @knittl Nitpick - fields are not inherited so they can't be abstract

Comment: @DStanley I do not know the type, the name and the number of the fields. I just want to force them to have at least one field of any type! Is that possible?

Comment: Not at compile time - you could use a static analysis tool or a custom "checker" using reflection but I do not know of a way to force a class to have a field.  What is the purpose?  Why do you need to impose that restriction?

Comment: @a.toraby: Then how do you reference those fields if you don't know their name and count? Tell us which specific problem you are trying to solve with your pattern.

Comment: @DStanley Please have a look at the question. I updated it. Thanks

Comment: @a.toraby You just mention a vague "convention" that you want to enforce.  Without more specifics I don't know a way to solve your problem. As it stands there's not a way to "force" a class to have a field.  So all a coder has to do is define a useless field and it passes your "convention"?

Comment: @DStanley Could you possibly take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/30712417/764809 Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you specifically want an abstract field or is a property sufficient?

How about the following?

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract int Field { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
    public override int Field { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do not know the type, the name and the number of the fields. I just want to force them to have at least one field of any type! Is that possible?

Comment: Without knowing the type you could using generics. I'm pretty sure this won't give you the solution you need.
Could you perhaps give a broader description of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Please have a look at the question. I updated it. Thanks

Comment: Since you are forcing everybody to inherit from a class which only enforces a certain aspect of the class layout you are restricting them in many ways which are not useful.
Consider using other tools to enforce class layout and not OOP.