# How to force others to obey a specific layout for a child class?

Tags: c#, oop, reflection

I have an abstract class as follows:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    public abstract void run();
}
```

There are some child nodes that may have several properties as input and output. But all the operation is done just in `run()` method that each Node should implement. For example a Node that draws a line could be something like this:

```
public class LineNode : Node
{
    [Input]
    public Point a;
    [Input]
    public Point b;
    [Output]
    public Line line;
    public override void run()
    {
        line = new Line(a, b);
        // draw line ...
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class Input : System.Attribute
{

}
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class Output : System.Attribute
{

}
```

As you see I don't have any prior information about fields in the child classes. **** For a Node to be a valid node in convention, It is just required to have at least one output.**** I want to force all other users to have at least one output in their Nodes so I can find it by reflection by looking for a field that [Output] attribute is applied to.

Is this possible?

And if this is, Is it the best way?

Thanks for any help

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409031/force-attribute-usage-in-subclass-of-abstract-superclass) the same issue raised but the suggested solution settled it in the run time. I was looking for an Object Oriented solution though. Which one is more logical actually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force attribute usage in subclass of abstract superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409031/force-attribute-usage-in-subclass-of-abstract-superclass)

Comment: are u asking something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927230/force-attribute-declaration-in-derived-classes

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409031/force-attribute-usage-in-subclass-of-abstract-superclass

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```
public interface IRunnable<T>
{
    T Run();
}
```

And then every class that implements this interface must provide this run method and return a (strongly typed ) result.

Or if the run method does not return the result

```
public interface IRunnable<T>
{
    void Run();
    T Value {get;}
}
public class LineNode : IRunnable<Line>
{
    [Input]
    public Point a;
    [Input]
    public Point b;

    private Line line;
    public Line Value { get{return line;}}
    public override void run()
    {
    line = new Line(a, b);
    // draw line ...
    }
```

}

Comment: This looks good for having one and only one output - what about multiple outputs?

Comment: What if there are multiple outputs of different types?

Comment: You mean return different objects?The interface is generic.You can return whatever you want and have type safety

Comment: Imagine a `node` implementation that has two outputs, a `Circle` and a `Line`.  would you just end up making an `IRunnable<List<Object>>`?

Comment: Define an interface for the different results, like `INodeResult` and use an `ICollection<INodeResult> Results {get;}` in the interface

Comment: and/or even combine this solution with an OutputDefinition as in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Define something like this in your base class:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    [Output]
    public abstract object DefaultOuptut;
    public abstract void run();
}
```

And now your line class might look like this:

```
public class LineNode : Node
{
    [Input]
    public Point a;
    [Input]
    public Point b;
    [Output]
    public Line line;
    [Output]
    public override object DefaultOutput { get { return line; } }

    public override void run()
    {
        line = new Line(a, b);
        // draw line ...
    }
}
```

You could use some generic typing as well on the default object:

```
public abstract class Node<T>
{
   [Output]
   public abstract T DefaultOutput;
   public abstract void run();
}
```

This would still allow for other outputs that are not `T`s.

Comment: Our solutions are similar.The only problem with yours is the you don't know the return type of your method.You cannot use it without a cast

Comment: Generics could be implemented in my solution too, but the generic typing would only apply to the DefaultOutput insted of all outputs.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an Interface `IOutputDefinition` and defining an abstract `ICollection<IOutputDefinition>` in the `Node`-class. All Implementers have to fill this in order to enable your code to determine which outputs the implementation will produce.

You may define any Metadata-Properties like Name, Output-Type, ... or even a property containing a Getter-Expression for the Output in the Interface